# Samba share can't serve Win 10 since fall creator update - System error 1272

Tags: networking, samba, windows-10, file-sharing

I *think* I had this working awhile back, but now I can't connect over a Win 10 machine. Apparently this is because Windows (since the fall creator update to version 1709) no longer allows logging in as a guest - at least the Enterprise Edition. However I get the same error even when I specify the user/pass word in the net command like this:

```
C:\>net use u: \\192.168.12.12\transfer /user:mike pass
System error 1272 has occurred.

You can't access this shared folder because your organization's security policies
 block unauthenticated guest access. 
 These policies help protect your PC from unsafe or malicious devices on the network.
```

The share configuration in `smb.conf` looks like this:

```
[transfer]
   comment = file transfer share
   path = /usr/local/transfer
   writable = yes
   browsable = yes
   valid users = mike
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777
```

It should be possible to configure this so that it works securely... some evidence is that my QNAP server - which uses Samba - continues to work (but with a non-guest user).

This is a Microsoft blurb on the issue:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4046019/guest-access-smb2-disabled-by-default-in-windows-10-server-2016

I am really not sure what I should try next - the number of Samba configuration settings is vast. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you suspecting that this is specific to the Enterprise Edition?

Comment: I think this restriction - the default not allowing guest login to a samba share - even when it is required - is specific to the EE. Higher security standards I suppose.

Comment: I read about a flag to disable it, but that won't help me for long as Group Policy will just periodically flatten it again.

Comment: Is there a way to specify Samba version 3.00 on the `net` command?

Comment: Why? I guess you can enable/disable the various versions: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2696547/how-to-detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and

Comment: The 1272 error that you received when passing a user name and password makes no sense ... unless you [1] are not using the samba password for mike ( sudo smbpasswd -a mike ) then you would be converted to a guest user and  [2] you have "guest ok = yes' in the [global] section of /etc/samba/smb.conf. Run - without quotes "testparm -s" on the samba server to find out. I don't have Win10EE so there is no way I can try to reproduce this error. Sorry.

Comment: Good Info thx. Will check those things out.

Comment: I needed to get this working again, and tried our your suggestion - basically using `smbpasswd` to set an extra (and different from my login password) for `mike`. Everything worked then.

Comment: If you write it up as an answer will be happy to accept and upvote.\

Comment: Solution posted [on superuser.com by @michaelkrieger](https://superuser.com/a/1451160/666874)
The short answer seems to be that Windows will no longer allow the connection if Samba is allowing any sort of guest access.  Click on the link I provided, and the relevant smb.conf settings are provided.  Also, be sure that you have set a Samba password for the user you are connecting as. (see follow-up comment from @KeyszerS )